# I want to run three loops by parallel processing Without using Pthreads?

Tags: php, parallel-processing

look at my script, if i run one loop, it takes 3 sec, right? ( each loop has a sleep(1) )
So running 3 loops will take about 9 sec.
I want this:
I run parallel all 3 loops, to be finished in total 3 sec.
I want to perform it without using threads and pthreads php

name: 0 started at: 15:51:43
name: 1 started at: 15:51:44
name: 2 started at: 15:51:45

---

day: 0 started at: 15:51:43
day: 1 started at: 15:51:44
day: 2 started at: 15:51:45

---

week: 0 started at: 15:51:43
week: 1 started at: 15:51:44
week: 2 started at: 15:51:45

this is my code

```
<?php

function getResult(){


echo "<br>";    
for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++){
     echo "name: " . $i . " started at:" . date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
     sleep(1);
}
     echo"<hr>";
for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++){
     echo "day: " . $i . " started at:" . date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
     sleep(1);
}
     echo"<hr>";

for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++){
     echo "week: " . $i . " started at:" . date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
     sleep(1);
}
     echo `enter code here`"<hr>";


getResult();

?>
```

That does not work. I want to run this code in parallel.
I want to run three different loops at the same time.

Comment: *without using threads and pthreads* is there any reason for this?

Comment: Its my task to perform it without using pthreads and threads. I have tried to do it in many scenarios but that does not work. I want to run three loops at the same time to save time in my case its taking 9 sec to execute cause its running one by one i want it to take three sec to save time.